# Как запустить одно приложение внутри другого?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Есть приложение А и Б. Нужно как-то запустить приложение Б в А. Тоесть в интерфейсе одного приложения создать контейнер и в него загрузить другое. (Что бы вокруг интерфейса одного приложения был интерфейс другого.)
Получилось объяснить?

Comment: А зачем? Что это за задача такая?

Comment: и чтобы это приложение внутри себя запустило еще одно, а то еще одно :)